# Why does copy constructor not need to check whether the input object pointers to itself or not？

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

As the code below, the copy assignment operator has to check whether the input object pointers to itself or not. I wonder why copy constructor does not need to do the same check.

I am novice in C++.I would be grateful to have some help on this question.

```
  class rule_of_three
    {
        char* cstring; // raw pointer used as a handle to a dynamically-allocated memory block

        void init(const char* s)
        {
            std::size_t n = std::strlen(s) + 1;
            cstring = new char[n];
            std::memcpy(cstring, s, n); // populate
        }
     public:
        rule_of_three(const char* s = "") { init(s); }

        ~rule_of_three()
        {
            delete[] cstring;  // deallocate
        }

        rule_of_three(const rule_of_three& other) // copy constructor
        { 
            init(other.cstring);
        }

        rule_of_three& operator=(const rule_of_three& other) // copy assignment
        {
            if(this != &other) {
                delete[] cstring;  // deallocate
                init(other.cstring);
            }
            return *this;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Because when you construct by copy, the constructed object can't be the one that is copied... You can test, but the condition will never happen.

Comment: @IgorR. But storing references to uninitialized objects is allowed, isn't it? I think it is.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How can you get a reference to an uninitialized object?

Comment: @user207421 Simple, pass it to its own copy ctor. :P `MyClass foo(foo);`.

Comment: @IgorR. We can call it "uninitialized storage", but the point still stands.

Comment: As a side point - it looks like you are doing all your pointer management within this class for `cstring`. I think alot of your memory management "work" goes away if you replace that with a `unique_ptr` (or shared_ptr depending what you are doing with it). Since the unique ptr can be re-assigned (deleting the old instance) and also tidies up on destruction...

Comment: @code_fodder I could get your idea.Does it have some relation with the question?

Comment: @sunshilong369 not directly, as I was saying, its more of a side point, but it might make your life a bit easier - using smart pointers to make managing the memory a little bit simpler :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-*assignment* sometimes happens, it's a part of a normal use of a class.

Passing a not-yet-constructed object as a parameter to its own copy (or move) constructor is not normal. While not undefined behavior per se<sup>**1**</sup>, there are no good reasons to do it, and it normally doesn't happen. It can happen accidentally, or if someone is deliberately trying to break your class.

Because of that, traditionally copy (and move) constructors don't check for `&other != this`.

But nothing stops you from doing it, if you want some extra safety:

```
rule_of_three(const rule_of_three& other) // copy constructor
{ 
    assert(&other != this);
    init(other.cstring);
}
```

---

<sup>**1**</sup> [`[basic.life]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7) seems to allow that, as long as you don't access the not-yet-constructed object itself. Taking an address of it using `&` is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have simple objects like Stormtroopers:

```
class Stormtrooper
    {
        char* cstring; // raw pointer used as a handle to a dynamically-allocated memory block

        void clone(const char* s)
        {
            std::size_t n = std::strlen(s) + 1;
            cstring = new char[n];
            std::memcpy(cstring, s, n); // populate
        }
     public:
        Stormtrooper(const char* s = "I am a Stormtrooper clone") { clone(s); }

        ~Stormtrooper()
        {
            delete[] cstring;  // deallocate
        }

        Stormtrooper(const Stormtrooper& other) // copy constructor
        { 
            clone(other.cstring);
        }

        Stormtrooper& operator=(const Stormtrooper& other) // copy assignment
        {
            if(this != &other) {
                delete[] cstring;  // deallocate
                clone(other.cstring);
            }
            return *this;
        }
    };
```

If you want to assign une Stormtrooper to another it is useful to check if the two Stormtroopers are already identical or not (and they usually are). In this way you avoid the clone() operation, because the Stormtroopers are already identical.

But if you want to create a new Stormtrooper, and you want him to be identical to another Stormtrooper (as usual) you can copy-construct it and in this case the clone() operation will be performed correctly.

In this way you can create an entire army of Stormtroopers quite easily.